# Jquery getJson page never finishes loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

The following code calls the JSON and displays the results but then it seems like the page never completes loading.  The browser still says connecting and view source never displays
Any ideas?

```
<script>
function getroadcondFiles () {
    jQuery.support.cors = true
//  electdiv=electdiv+"</center><br>";
    $.getJSON('http://example.com?callback=?',function(dataa){
//   console.log("before each");
     //console.log(dataa.result.totalCount);
     $.each(dataa.roadid, function(i,item){
    document.write(item.desc+"<br>");
    document.write(item.overstat[0]+"<br>");
    document.write(item.weatherstat[0]+"<br>");
    document.write(item.pavementstat[0]+"<br>");
    });

    ;}).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(errorThrown); });
    ;}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$=jQuery;
getroadcondFiles();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for an [`$.ajaxError`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) or use your browser's debugger to get more insight in to the failure. Without knowing if the json call is failing (and no error besides "this doesn't work") there's no way to tell what's failing.

I recommend using `$.ajax` and the `error` property to determine if there is a problem occurring with the query. one you find out if it's the query or the script you'll be better informed on how to correct the issue.

it may not even be ajax failing though, it could be another script still processing. Once again, use your browser's debugging tools to get more insight in to what's actually the original problem.

Comment: Just saw your `.error` call now, but it still could be AJAX failing (or a resource just having trouble loading). Either way, we would need more information about the page to build a conclusion as to why it's idling.

Comment: This is the only code on the page.  Here is the jsonp call http://php.pressconnects.com/roadcond?callback=?

Comment: Note sure if it's _that_ big a deal, but [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com) says the response is malformed. -- Nevermind,t hat's because I'm exempting the jsonp callback. :tired:

Comment: So, [when broken out](http://jsfiddle.net/wVVDJ/1/embedded/result/) it works fine and doesn't hang. Chances are it's another script on the page or some other resources that's having trouble loading.

Comment: Figured it out it was the document.write calls.  Removing them and having the data fill a div fixed the problem.